# Gem não disponível

Tags: ruby

Erro:

> Cound not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando uma virtual box, pode ser isto?

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer? Qual foi o comando que você rodou para chegar nisso?

Comment: tenta o comando `gem install jquery-rails`,  para instalar a sua gem pendente

Comment: Verifique se a máquina virtual tem acesso ¡a internet.

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando essa a gem `jquery-rails`, tente:

```
sudo gem install jquery-rails
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem que instalar o NodeJs em sua maquina virtual !

Execute o comando no terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

e depois tenta criar um novo projeto.

Comment: valeu galera desde já agradeço a todos